# Compiling...The application panicked (crashed)

Tags: solidity, foundry, rust

- If anyone is facing this issue while compiling a smart contract using `foundry` & getting this error

```js
forge build                 
[⠃] Compiling...The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  checksum not found
Location: ~/.cargo/git/checkouts/ethers-rs-c3a7c0a0ae0fe6be/01d3e43/ethers-solc/src/compile/mod.rs:463

This is a bug. Consider reporting it at https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case problem has gone when I specify version of solc in foundry.toml config file:

```
solc_version = "0.8.19"
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can fix this by running

```cpp
forge build --no-auto-detect
```

- I was going through the issues section of the project & found this issue was solved back in 2021. I don't why we are getting this again. I'm sure I'm not the only one. Hope it can help someone.
- Same with testing as well

```cpp
forge test --no-auto-detect
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran `foundryup` and it compiled after that